# How to create a database in oracle 11g express edition?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I have installed Oracle 11g XE in my machine.  Now I connecting it via System schema. How do I create a database of my own. Just like in MS SQL using

```
CREATE DATABASE database_name;
```

How do I create a database like this in oracle 11g XE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oracle is not like SQL Server.  You don't get to create multiple databases (though things have changed since version 12, but it doesn't apply here anyways). With Oracle 11g XE, you only get one database instance called `XE`.

Instead, what you'll want to do is to create yourself a *user* within that `XE` database instance, which in effect results in an associated *schema* that you can use to create *objects* (tables, views, etc.)  You can create more users (schemas) as needed.

For more detailed information: [Database Express Edition Getting Started Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/admin.112/e18585/toc.htm#XEGSG101)

Comment: Thank  u for the reply. So u mean multiple  databases can be created in oracle 12c.

Comment: Yes, though again, keep in mind that Oracle <> SQL Server, so trying to work with Oracle requires a different way of thinking.  If you're curious about the support for "multiple databases" in Oracle 12: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database/multitenant-part1-pdbs-2193987.html